# By enter my website, automaticly added another url after my domain name

Tags: url, dns

I created a domain called (tasvir-graphic.de) but whenever I Enter to the website, the URL changes automatically to (https://www.tasvir-graphic.de/tasvir-graphic/) with not found page. I need to delete the second (tasvir-graphic) from URL and enter the page again and it works.
Does any one know where the problem is?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to redirect http to https using .htaccess file and then the problem solved.